# When should I use DateTime(timezone=True) and when TIMESTAMP(timezone=True)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, sqlalchemy

Say I want to store aware `datetime`s (i.e., timestamps with timezone offsets) in a database using SQLAlchemy, and I want it to Just Work™ with as many types of relational databases (SQLite, PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle, etc.) as possible.  SQLAlchemy offers two types for this purpose: [`DateTime`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.DateTime) and its subclass [`TIMESTAMP`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.TIMESTAMP).  Both take an optional `timezone` argument that can be set to `True` in order to store timezone-aware values.  However, I'm not clear on what the difference between the two types is or why/when I should use one over the other.

Interestingly, the `DateTime` docs say:

> For timezone support, use at least the `TIMESTAMP` datatype, if not the dialect-specific datatype object.
>
> [On the `timezone` argument:] It is recommended to make use of the `TIMESTAMP` datatype directly when using this flag, as some databases include separate generic date/time-holding types distinct from the timezone-capable TIMESTAMP datatype, such as Oracle.

... which raises the question, if I should be using `TIMESTAMP`, then what is `DateTime` for?  What exactly can go wrong with using the wrong column type?